# How to select all drivers?

Tags: selection-tools, drivers, select

When I'm importing mesh to blender I have a lot of drivers which I need to delete. It's too long to select each driver, and I've tried to use shift+LMB, ctrl+LMB, ctrl-A, but can't select all the drivers. I tried to use "select" option but it's inactive too:
[image]
How can I select or delete all the drivers?